# Kaplan-Meier multiple group comparisons

Tags: r, survival-analysis

Lets say I have the following data frame

```
library(survival)
library(multcomp)
data(cml)
cml$group<-sample(1:5, 507, replace=T)
plot(survfit(Surv(time=cml$time, cml$status)~cml$group))
(survdiff(Surv(time=cml$time, cml$status)~cml$group))
```

How can I perform multiple comparison test comparing for example group0 vs. all other groups? Or every group with each other?

Is there a nice way of plotting these multiple comparisons (as for example in `plot.TukeyHSD()` in `aov()`?

Answer (score 1):

There is an example in the generalsiminf.pdf of multcomp. Simplified here

```
library(multcomp)
library(survival)
if (!file.exists("AML_Bullinger.rda"))
  load(url("http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/~hothorn/data/AML_Bullinger.rda", open = "r"))
risk <- rep(0, nrow(clinical))
rlev <- levels(clinical[, "Cytogenetic.group"])
risk[clinical[, "Cytogenetic.group"] %in% rlev[c(7,8,4)]] <- "low"
risk[clinical[, "Cytogenetic.group"] %in% rlev[c(5, 9)]] <- "intermediate"
risk[clinical[, "Cytogenetic.group"] %in% rlev[-c(4,5, 7,8,9)]] <- "high"
risk <- as.factor(risk)
names(clinical)[6] <- "FLT3"
save(clinical,file="AML_Bullinger.rda")
smod <- survreg(Surv(time, event) ~ Sex + Age + WBC+risk,
                 data = clinical)
summary(glht(smod, linfct = mcp(risk = "Tukey")))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have one question. survreg fits a parametric survival regression model. What I have is simple KM analysis estimates. Can i use survreg and multicomp to make multiple comparisons of KM estimates?

Comment: Good point. I do not know about KM multiple test packages, but in case this is serious, I would probably go Bayes (if your boss/editor permits) http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Survival.html

Comment: Try. The question is certainly valid.

Comment: OK i did. Lets see what comes up. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31077/kaplan-meier-multiple-group-comparisons